# How to install JDK8 on Ubuntu 18.04 64Bit

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

i have the package jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz  on my pc how to install it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer
java -version
```

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what this command does. A plain command or command sequence is rarely considered an answer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)